# How to destroy and reinitialize FredHQ jQuery Roundabout Plugin based on Window Width

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, window-resize

I am using [**FredHQ Roundabout (jQuery Plugin)**](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/) and need this plugin to be disabled below 480 pixels. It's being called by a class so I tried adding a remove class:

```
<script>
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(this).width() > 480) {
        $('#menuSection').removeClass('roundAbout');   
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize();
});
</script>
```

When I remove the class, the script is still active. I need some help deactivating this and reactivating it on the fly.

Comment: What is the name of the plugin?

Comment: you need to unbind the action, removing class will not help

Comment: @user1642465 Updated my answer with much more info. Why don't you get rid of this anonymity and join SO for good. I guarantee you'll be coming back here alot, so you might as well make a full account! :P

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what plugin you are using, it's hard to supply an answer. The plugin may contain a "destroy" method. However, there is possibly another way.  Maintain a clone of the roundabout element, then replace it with the clone:

### Example

> **Long Answer** <sub>*Includes detail explination*
> *If you would like just the code, please scroll on down the page*</sub>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // First I establish variables for the clone and timer we will be using
    var clnRoundabout, tmrCloneReset;

    //  This is equivalent to $(document).ready
    $(function() {

        //  First things first, clone the main HTML for later use as needed
        clnRoundabout = $('#menuSection').clone();

        //  Second, establish the first on screen roundabout 
        //    (you may want to do a screen width check first)
        $('#menuSection').roundabout();

        //  Here we call the resize method on window so we know when the window size is changing
        $(window).resize(function(e) {

            //  This is simply to clear the timer so it is not run twice within too short a time period
            //  What might confuse you here is the call before its established
            // the reason is simple, if you have your mouse down on the window border,
            //  and you are constantly moving the border, thus resizing the window,
            //  then this method will be called 1000 times a second!
            //  this is why we need the timer and we need to clear it everytime this method is called.
            //  by clearing it and recalling it everytime we can assure that the method is only fired once, 
            //  depending on the TIME parameter at the end of setTimeout
            clearTimeout(tmrCloneReset);

            //  now of course we establish the timer i just spoke of,
            //  notice at the end i set the time to 250, that is .250 of a second
            //  you can try it with different times, but i have found this time to be optimal
            tmrCloneReset = setTimeout(function() {

                //  Now for your width comparison, pretty straight forward here
                if ($(this).width() < 480) {
                    //  here I create a variable of the original clone,
                    //  I know seeing me clone the clone can seem confusing, here is the reason
                    //  We only want to use ALL new HTML, thus I can't use our old clone variable
                    //  for anything other than Copying "FROM"
                    //  this way we always have fresh HTML to replace the old HTML with!
                    // Make more sense now? if not, please comment 
                    //  and I'll help you wrap your head around it with an analogy or something
                    var tmpClone = clnRoundabout.clone();
                    //  Inserts cloned version with same ID and removes original
                    //  TADA, Fresh new HTML without any of the previous classes or css changes from the plugin tied to it!
                    $('#menuSection').after(tmpClone).remove();
                }
                else {
                    //  Here i'm simply checking to see if the roundabout plugin has already been called on our HTML, 
                    //  if it has, then let's not call it again, 
                    //  remember, as mentioned before, this event can fire up to 1000x a second!
                    if (!$('#menuSection').hasClass('roundabout-holder')) {
                        //  If the class is not existant,then we know the roundabout plugin has not been called!
                        //  Let's call it!
                        $('#menuSection').roundabout(); // or whatever your roundaboutcall is
                    }
                }
            //  Here is the end of the setTimeout function
            //  This is the time I referred to earlier
            //  time here is measured in milliseconds
            //  thus 1 == .001Seconds
            //  and 1000 == 1Seconds
            //  and 10000 == 10Seconds
            }, 250); // Here i'm set to .25Seconds
        });
    })
</script>
```

<strike>A tiny bit more info would be helpful in better answering this question</strike>

> **Short Answer**<sub>*Just the code*</sub>

```
var clnRoundabout, tmrCloneReset;
$(function() {
    clnRoundabout = $('#menuSection').clone();
    $('#menuSection').roundabout();
    $(window).resize(function(e) {
        clearTimeout(tmrCloneReset);
        tmrCloneReset = setTimeout(function() {
            if ($(this).width() < 480) {
                var tmpClone = clnRoundabout.clone();
                $('#menuSection').after(tmpClone).remove();
            }
            else {
                if (!$('#menuSection').hasClass('roundabout-holder')) {
                    $('#menuSection').roundabout();
                }
            }
        }, 250);
    });
})
```

Comment: @user1642465 LoL, that's the same one I used, first pick on Google of course. Anyway, look at example. The code i used there works. If you need more explanation, let me know.

Comment: Oh, and unless  I'm mistaken, that plugin does **not** have a destroy method. Thus the method I use of maintaining a clone of the List and replacing it as necessary.

Comment: Is your solution intended to add the class back in when the window is made larger than 480px? It works great for me resizing down. I just don't fully understand what's happening in with the clone function, so I'm having a hard time adjusting it to work the way I want.

Comment: @user1642465 I'll break it down line by line within next 24 hours. just gimmie a minute. Oh and "long story, short". The reason I even check for the class is because the plugin adds it. Thus, if it has the class then we dont need to reinitialize it, but if it doesn't have the class then it came from the clone and the window size is now larger, thus it needs reinitialized

Answer (score 0):

This guy did this successfully and you can download his modified version of Roundabout here,
https://github.com/mattstauffer/roundabout